# MYSQL users have privileges I did not grant them

Tags: mysql, database, privileges

I created the `test_remote_bdd` database with the `root` MYSQL account, to which I granted all privileges to the `remote_tester` user, with the following commands:

```
CREATE DATABASE test_remote_bdd;
GRANT ALL ON test_remote_bdd.* TO remote_tester@'87.235.20.21' IDENTIFIED BY 'youisaremotetester';
```

I was quite surprised to discover that another user, `ministry-admin`, also have all privileges on this database. I double checked the history of MYSQL command, and I am 100% positive that I did not granted privileges to `ministry-admin` on the `test_remote_bdd` database.

Any idea why `ministry-admin` has privileges I did not granted him?
It is actually all other MYSQL users who were granted full privileges on the new `test_remote_bdd` database.

EDIT:
If I check the privileges granted for each user using:

```
SHOW GRANTS for 'someuser'@'somehost';
```

The results are what they should be, meaning that only `remote_tester` has privileges over `test_remote_bdd`.

Comment: Where are you hosting your db server? Maybe it's a user set up by your hosting provider.

Comment: Hi Lansen,
All this is happening on my laptop, locally. I am the only one controlling which user is granted which privilege. 
Thanks for the suggestion though